# How to escape single quote in string literal using MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySql table `person_details` which contains `p_id` and `p_name`. Now, if I want to insert a record where p_name contains a single quote `'`, I'd execute it this way-

`insert into person_details values (1, 'D\'souza');`

Now, I'm trying to execute the same through a java code this way-

`insert into person_details values (1, 'D\\\'souza');`

and I get MySQLSyntaxErrorException.

Anything wrong?

Comment: use the urlencode() function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question directly, double the quotes.

```
insert into person_details values (1, 'D''souza');
```

But I rather parameterized the query using `PreparedStatement`.

Here are the PROs:

- avoid from SQL Injection
- doesn't need to use single quotes.

example,

```
String str = "insert into person_details values (?, ?)";
query = con.prepareStatement(str);
query.setInt(1, 1);
query.setString(2, "D'souza");
query.executeUpdate();
```

- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: +1 Prepared statements are the way to go here if the data is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Simply Great sir. I also tried all combinations of \\\' , \\' ,\' Everything returned me SQL Syntax Error. It worked awesome

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, you use `''` for a single `'` inside a string:

```
insert into person_details values (1, 'D''souza');
```

[Link to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)

But that's only for when you're providing the data literally, such as an SQL script to pre-populate a table with data you control, etc. If you're receiving that string from an external source (an end user, for instance, or an external system) then presumably you won't be writing a literal, but rather using a string variable. In that case, you want to use prepared statements as [JW. describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15198645/157247). Why: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `"`

```
insert into person_details values (1, "D'souza");
```

Comment: Unless, of course, you're using [ANSI quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

It will also take care of SQL Injections