# How to insert a string with an apostrophe as the value of the mysql database field with java and j-connector?

Tags: java, mysql, string

I have a database with a "username" field and with Java I insert the values ​​into the database. I tried to enter the username "l'ornitorinco" but the program does not work (crashes). I know that when I insert an apostrophe string with phpMyAdmin like "l'ornitorinco" it is sent in this way "l'ornitorinco". I should probably analyze the string and insert the apostrophe at the appropriate point (with a for loop from 0 to string.length), but does anyone know a more appropriate method? I had read about a method to set the strings for mysql use, but I not remember.

Comment: will escape character \ help?

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes I don't understand what you mean

Comment: it was something like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844595/how-can-i-make-java-print-quotes-like-hello#:~:text=print(%22%5C%22Hello%5C,r%22%20and%20%22%5Cn%22` but you have your answer so all good~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a **`PreparedStatement`**, as its `setString()` method allows you to include apostrophes on the value, making it much simpler than *playing the single/doble quote game*.

```
String queryString = "insert into username values (?)";
query = con.prepareStatement(queryString);
query.setString(1, "l'ornitorinco");
query.executeUpdate();
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198580/how-to-escape-single-quote-in-string-literal-using-mysql-from-java) for more info. Hope it helps!